# CakePHP: authErrors, only in Safari

Tags: cakephp, safari

So I've set checkAgent to false, but I'm still getting an authError in Safari on allowed actions. Things are fine in other browsers.

The error always seems to happen on a page that is using a lot of JS and some AJAX. What could be causing this?

Comment: It's the general auth error, from the Auth Component.

Comment: I hinted that we'd need to see the error, but - I guess my subtlety didn't work.  Please post the error.